# go 1.14 to 1.17 update -> modules not working anymore

Tags: go

After updating Go from 1.14 to 1.17 I'm getting this error:

```
main.go:10:2: no required module provides package github.com/gin-gonic/gin: \
go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; \
see 'go help modules'
```

I used to be able to fix that with `go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin` but now that doesn't help. Did something change?

Comment: *"Did something change?"* -- Yes, see: https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command & https://golang.org/doc/go1.17#go-command (1.15 made no changes to the module stuff AFAICT).

Comment: From 1.16 module-aware mode is enabled by default, and your project has no `go.mod` file which is what causes the problem. To turn your project into a go module simply run `go mod init <module-path>` in the root directory.

Comment: If you have no go.mod, then you weren’t using modules in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can repro this if I have a file like this:

```
package hello
import _ "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
```

and run these commands:

```
go mod init hello
go build
```

Fix for me is running this command:

```
go mod tidy
```

Comment: Excellent. The official tutorial at https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/web-service-gin is already out of date then :)

Answer (score 3):

As of [Go 1.16](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command), “Module-aware mode is enabled by default, regardless of whether a `go.mod` file is present in the current working directory or a parent directory. More precisely, the `GO111MODULE` environment variable now defaults to `on`.”

See the [Migrating to Go Modules](https://go.dev/blog/migrating-to-go-modules) blog post for a quick overview of how to migrate, or [Tutorial: Create a Go Module](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation) we must use `go install example.com/cmd@latest` instead of `go get` for `go 1.17+`